# Mathematical Induction proof for a cubic equation.

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations

If $ x^3  = x +1$, prove by induction that $ x^{3n}  = a_{n}x + b_n + \frac {c_n}{x}$, where $a_1=1, b_1=1, c_1=0$ and 
$a_n =  a_{n-1}  + b_{n-1}, b_n = a_{n-1} + b_{n-1} + c_{n-1}, c_n = a_{n-1} + c_{n-1}$ for $n=2,3,\dots $

For $n=1$ we have $x_3 = a_1x + b_1 + \frac {c_1}{x}$  = x + 1 + $\frac{0}{x}$ = x + 1, which is true.

Assume the case for $n=k$ is true, so $x^{3k} = a_kx + b_k + \frac{c_k}{x}$

So for $n = k+1$ (and using $a_n =  a_{n-1}  + b_{n-1}, b_n = a_{n-1} + b_{n-1} + c_{n-1}, c_n = a_{n-1} + c_{n-1}$ for $n=2,3,...), $ we have:

$ \begin{align}
x^{3(k+1)} &= (a_{k+1-1}x + b_{k+1-1}){x}  + (a_{k+1-1} + b_{k+1-1}  + c_{k+1-1}) +  
( \frac{(a_{k+1-1} + c_{k+1-1})}{x}) \\
&= (a_k + b_k){x} + ( a_k + b_k + c_k) + \frac{(a_k + c_k)}{x} \\ 
&= a_{k+1}{x} + b_{k+1} + \frac{c_{k+1}}{x} \\\end{align} $

This is the same form as $ x^{3k} $ but for n=k+1. 
Therefore, if the result is true for k, it is also true for (k+1).

Would you proceed like this or would you add the $(k+1)$th term and show that it is equal to the $k$th term with $n$ (or $k$) replaced by $k+1$?

Comment: I'm not certain about the notation. Could you typeset your question? Surround mathematics by \$ (maths here) \$. If you need a subscript, use _ (e.g. \$ a_n \$ produces $a_n$). If you need a superscript, use ^ similarly. If you need longer subscripts, use braces to group things (e.g. \$ k^{n+1} \$ produces $k^{n+1}$).

Comment: It's hard to figure out what's being said here with the notation... could you have a look at: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?

Comment: I submitted an edit that fixes it, but I'm waiting for it to be reviewed, so until then or someone with privilege fixes it, it'll have to do for now.

Comment: Did you intend the first line to say "then $x^{3n} =$ ..." rather than $x_{3n} = $...? If not, what is $x_i$?

Comment: I just made the final edit. It looks better now, there are a lot of subscripts but the term you mentioned was meant to be $ x^{3n} $

Comment: but something is still wrong I am afraid...you have $x^{3(k+1)}=\dots=x^{3k}$, are you sure that is what you want?

Comment: If it is part of the mathematical induction process, then the case for k+1 should also be true for k. So it should be the case here.

Comment: No, it cannot, but let's assume for a moment it would: then $x^{3(k+1)}=x^{3k+3}=x^{3k}*x^{3}=x^{3k}\Rightarrow x^3=1$ which would be a contradiction to your assumption

Comment: But does $ x^3 $ =1?

Answer (score 5):

You should put "$=$" between things ALREADY KNOWN to be equal, not with things you are trying to prove to be equal.  You should not start a chain of equalities with the very equality you're trying to prove.

Thus
\begin{align}
x^{3(k+1)} & = x^3 x^{3k} & & \text{(This known, by routine algebra.)} \\[10pt]
& = x^3 ( a_kx + b_k + c_k x^{-1} ) & & \text{(This comes from the induction hypothesis.)} \\[10pt]
& = (x+1)( a_kx + b_k + c_k x^{-1} ) & & \text{(This is true by hypothesis.)} \\[10pt]
& = a_k x^2 + (a_k+b_k)x + (c_k+b_k) + c_k x^{-1} & & \text{(true by routine algebra)} \\[10pt]
& = \frac{a_k x^3} x + (a_k+b_k)x + (c_k+b_k) + c_k x^{-1} & & \text{(ditto)} \\[10pt]
& = \frac{a_k (x+1)} x + (a_k+b_k)x + (c_k+b_k) + c_k x^{-1} & & \text{(by hypothesis)} \\[10pt]
& = (a_k+b_k)x + (a_k + c_k+b_k) + (a_k+c_k) x^{-1} & & \text{(routine algebra again)}
\end{align}

Comment: very clear! Just one small wording thing, your 3rd equality, do you really call this ***hypothesis***?It sounds somewhat strange to my ears, I'd rather call it assumption.

Comment: In mathematics, when one states a theorem, one says "Assume that$\ldots$" or "Suppose$\ldots$", and then one writes "Then [the following is true]."  Etc.  The parts before "then" are "assumptions" or "hypotheses".  That is standard nomenclature.  The point is that the theorem is claimed to be true in every instance in which the hypotheses are true.  In other words, yes. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thank you for that! I wasn't aware of the fact that one can use - at least in a mathematical context - the two words "hypothesis" and "assumption" equivalently.

Comment: A good way to do it. Thanks. Yes, it is an assumption that we make in induction that the case for k is true. So that we can show that the case for (k+1) is also true.

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is that $x^3=x+1$ implies

$$x^2=1+{1\over x}\quad\text{and}\quad x^4=x^2+x=1+{1\over x}+x$$

So if $x^{3k}=a_kx+b_k+{c_k\over x}$ then

$$\begin{align}
x^{3(k+1)}&=x^3\cdot x^{3k}\\
&=x^3(a_kx+b_k+{c_k\over x})\\
&=a_kx^4+b_kx^3+c_kx^2\\
\end{align}$$

Now replace the $x^4$, $x^3$, and $x^2$ in the last line with $1+{1\over x}+x$, $x+1$, and $1+{1\over x}$, respectively, simplify, and voila.

Comment: Thanks for all your responses and edits. We all got to the same result in slightly different ways.

Comment: @J132, Michael Hardy, in his answer, makes a very good point about the proper way to proceed in writing up a proof.  In addition to starting with the conclusion, your approach winds up, in effect, concluding that $x^{3(k+1)}=x^{3k}$, which is not at all correct (as user190080 pointed out in comments).

Comment: I have reworded the answer in the original question. It no longer states an equality but the form of the equation (formula) for the n=k and n=k+1 cases is similar.

Comment: @J132, yes, I see you made some changes.  There are still problems with what's there, the main thing being, as Michael Hardy said, you are *starting* from the conclusion.  (Actually there's a typo, too:  the first line should have an $a_{k+1}x$ instead of just an $a_{k+1}$.  The other two lines also have some misplaced or missing $x$'s.)

Comment: I have made some more alterations.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Multiply $x^{3n}  = a_{n}x + b_n + \frac {c_n}{x}$ on the left by $x^3$ and on the right by $x+1$. Regroup and deduce a formula for $a_{n+1}$, $b_{n+1}$, $c_{n+1}$ in terms of $a_{n}$, $b_{n}$, $c_{n}$.